# Show that D is a ring of sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\nu$ a pre-measure on a ring $\mathcal{R}$.
show: $\mathcal{D}=\{A\in\mathcal{R}|\nu(A)=0\}$ is a ring

1. closed under union: $\nu(A\cup B)=\nu(A)+\nu(B)-\nu(A\cap B)=-\nu(A\cap B)$
2. closed under relative complement: $\nu(A\setminus B)=\nu(A)-\nu(B)=0$  but only if $B\subset A$

how can I show 1) and what if $B$ is not a subset of $A$ in 2)?

Comment: This follows by the monotonicity of $\nu$. If $\nu(A)=0$, then $\nu(S)=0$ for any $S\subseteq A$ whenever $S\in\mathcal{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Bernard Pan said, $\nu(S)=0$ for any $S\subset A$. 
And since $(A\cap B) \subset A$ and $(A\setminus B) \subset A \qquad \nu(A\cap B)=0\quad$ and $\quad\nu(A\setminus B)=0$